# DB2 SQL Exception while executing query

Tags: sql, db2, sqlexception

in DB2 while executing a query i got

SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016

does someone knows what this code means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some information [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ36474)
that you may find helpful